# Change getBitmapFromURL

Tags: java, android

I have image in my ListView. They are loaded as follows:

```
String iMages[] = {
     "http://www.thebiblescholar.com/android_awesome.jpg",
     "http://blogs-images.forbes.com/rogerkay/files/2011/07/Android1.jpg",
     "http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/android-market-leader-smartphone.jpg",
     "http://www.planmyworkshop.com/images/android.jpeg",
     "http://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/01-android2.jpg" 
};

ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap_array = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
for (int i = 0; i < iMages.length; i++) {
     Log.d("i-->" + i, "Url-->" + iMages[i]);
     Bitmap bit = getBitmapFromURL(iMages[i]);
     bitmap_array.add(bit);
}
```

How load them from res/drawable ? I tried different ways, but all the way past ...

Comment: did you google before that ask here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to decode a bitmap from your drawable folder:

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the images in your ListView are of type ImageView or subclasses (ImageButton, ZoomButton etc.).

If that is the case, just set the res image as background:

```
myImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Remember to do it only from UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

```
 String imageFileName = "launcher"; //  this is image file name
 String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
 int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+imageFileName , null, null);
 image_view.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId));
```